# How do I check if a product is in two categories?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

Inside `content-single-product.php`, im using an if statement to find out what category each product is in, which I have working:

```
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
                  
 if ( in_array( 'cat-1', $categories ) ) { ?>

  <h3>Category 1:</h3>
                    
 <?php } elseif ( in_array( 'cat-2', $categories ) ) { ?>
                    
 <h3>Category 2:</h3>

 <?php } else { ?>

 <h3>Bundle Products:</h3>
                                            
 <?php } ?>
```

But some products are in multiple categories, so how can i decide what happens under these instances?

Comment: Your loop can be replaced with `$categories = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );`

Comment: Could you go into more detail please @TomJNowell

Comment: It was just a comment offering a suggestion, it was not a solution/answer. The foreach loop isn't necessary, WP has a helper function for that called `wp_list_pluck`. As for your actual question, I think this can be solved using some common sense logic. I assume you understand the basic PHP for `if A and B`?